# How did the Unsullied travel in season 7 finale?

Tags: game-of-thrones

The Unsullied were stuck on Casterly Rock the last time we saw them. This episode showed them stand around the castle in King's Landing.

How did they get there?

Comment: They walked.....they weren't stuck on Casterly Rock...they just couldn't sail away. Also...that wasn't **all the Unsullied**

Comment: See - M&TV [**How did this army get here?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79647/how-did-this-army-get-here/79659#79659)

Comment: [One Weird Trick Lets the Unsullied March Across Westeros!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OORsz2d1H7s)

Comment: @Paulie_D even if that wasn't all the Unsullied, Greyworm surely made it.

Comment: @Skooba nailed it.. again =)

Comment: The same way everyone got everywhere this season; they teleported. Sure is lucky the Army of the Dead don't have this ability...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## They Walked

To explain further the Unsullied were never stuck at Casterly Rock in the first place. They took the rock and whilst they were busy doing so Euron and his fleet destroyed the Unsullied ships.

They presumably then left the Unsullied there with a long walk to wherever they needed to go, as it was they needed to go to King's Landing. They can easily do this by walking.

Lastly, along the way I doubt they would have had to fight anyone as the Lannister army appears to be spread thin but those commanded by Jaime will be back in King's Landing as Jaime and his captains are there. Also they need a force in case it is a trap and Dany decides to take action with her armies.

We also know that Euron is back at King's Landing, as he is present at the meeting, and that his fleet is there also. As you can see in the following clip.

So even if Euron could have besieged them somehow he isn't there to do so.

Comment: Which is kind of weird. Lannisters had a brilliant field commander like Ser Jaime Lannister. There are Lannister Armies in Riverlands. A line of march from CR to KL would see the Unsullied march on the Goldroad. This would be a very juicy opportunity to outflank them, with Lannisters marching down from Riverlands. Unsullied do not have any maesters or birds with them to carry the message to Dragonstone to call Daenerys and her dragons. But yet, they passed unmolested. Unless of course they marched after the Lannister agreed to meet for a Meeting and Tyrion arranged for their safe passage

Comment: @Aegon I'd assume they'd march afterwards but it still seems odd from Cersei's POV to not attack them. I guess if they'd have had 8 episodes they might have done that...

Comment: Though then she wouldn't have had chance to double cross them at the meeting properly.

Comment: that's of course if we assume they marched after the arrangement. Oh and on second thoughts, they could have easily captured the maester and ravens in CR and take them along. But if they marched before the arrangement, it was a sad sad blunder on part of top Lannister command. Unsullied are the core strength of Dany's conventional forces. One Red stroke could get the Lannisters rid of them. Unless of course they were aware of the chance but heldback to avoid another encounter with Drogon.

Comment: @Aegon True does appear though that the Dothraki are meant to arrive just after the Unsullied so maybe they didn't attack them if the Dothraki met them on the road.